# Loop executing multiple times

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

Getting a weird result out of this loop.  It is executing more times than it should be.  It should just keep displaying fib_2 as it gets recalculated.  What is going on?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

UPPERBOUND = 47
LOWERBOUND = 0

.data
userName        BYTE    33 DUP(0)   ;string to be entered by user
intro_1     BYTE    "Fibonacci Numbers", 0
intro_2     BYTE "Programmed by Marshall Todt", 0
prompt_1        BYTE    "What's your name? ", 0
intro_3     BYTE    "Hello, ", 0
intro_4     BYTE "Enter the number of Fibonacci terms to be displayed", 0
prompt_2        BYTE    "How many Fibonacci terms do you want? ", 0
intro_5     BYTE "Give the number as an integer in the range [1...46].", 0
error_1     BYTE    "Number of Fibonacci terms must be in the range [1-46].", 0
fibCount        DWORD ?
fib_1       DWORD 1
fib_2       DWORD 1
fib_3       DWORD ?
goodBye_1       BYTE "Answers certified by Marshall Todt.", 0
goodBye_2       BYTE    "Good-bye, ", 0
count       DWORD ?

.code
main PROC

;Introduction
mov     edx, OFFSET intro_1
call    WriteString
call    CrLf
mov     edx, OFFSET intro_2
call    WriteString
call    CrLf
call CrLf

;getUserData
mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_1
call    WriteString
mov     edx, OFFSET userName
mov     ecx, 32
call    ReadString


;userInstructions
mov     edx, OFFSET intro_3
call    WriteString
mov     edx, OFFSET userName
call    WriteString
call    CrLf
    mov     edx, OFFSET intro_4
call    WriteString
call    CrLf
mov     edx, OFFSET intro_5
call    WriteString
call    CrLf
reEnter:
call CrLf
mov     edx, OFFSET prompt_2
call    WriteString
mov     edx, OFFSET fibCount
mov     ecx, 32
call    ReadString

;mov      eax, fibCount
;cmp    eax, LOWERBOUND
;jg    reEnter         ;jumps to reEnter if the number of fibonacci terms is not higher than the LOWERBOUND
;mov      eax, fibCount
;cmp    eax, UPPERBOUND
;jl    reEnter          ;jumps to reEnter if the number of fibonacci terms is not lower than the UPPERBOUND

mov eax, fibCount
sub eax, 2
mov count, eax

;displayFibs
mov eax, fib_1
Call WriteDec
Call CrLf
L1: 
mov count, ecx
mov eax, fib_2
Call WriteDec
Call CrLf

;calculate Fibs
mov eax, fib_1
add eax, fib_2
mov fib_3, eax
mov eax, fib_2
mov fib_1, eax
mov eax, fib_3
mov fib_2, eax
mov ecx, count
loop L1

;farewell
 mov  edx, OFFSET goodBye_1
call WriteString
call CrLf
mov     edx, OFFSET goodBye_2
call    WriteString
mov     edx, OFFSET userName
call    WriteString
call    CrLf

exit    ; exit to operating system
main ENDP

END main
```

EDIT: added in the rest of the code

Comment: How many times does the loop execute? What is the value of `ecx` the first time you enter the loop? Are you sure that `WriteDec` and `CrLf` don't modify `ecx`?

Comment: I do not believe they modify ecx (but to be sure, I added the count variable to store and retrieve the count before the loop)  It executes 35 times in one test when it should execute twice

Comment: It seems to always execute 35 times regardless of inputted number

Comment: You need to show more of your code. Like where you initialize `ecx` before the loop, and where you declare your variables (`count`, `fib_1`, etc).

Comment: Okay, I will edit to show the whole code

Comment: From the looks of it, you're reading a string into `fibCount`, subtracting 2 from the `dword` made up of the first 4 characters of the string, and using that value as `count`. Aren't you missing a string-to-integer conversion somewhere?

Comment: Not sure how to convert to an integer in assembly language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you don't put the value of `count` in ecx before you start the loop. Your call to `ReadString` apparently stores the value in `fibCount`. You subtract 2 from that and store it in `count`, but you never change `ecx`. The only value that gets set in `ecx` is `32`.

I think you'll solve your problem with:

```
    call CrLf
    mov ecx, count ; <== add this line
L1:
    mov count, ecx
```

Comment: did that, and it made it an infinite loop

Comment: You seem to be filling `fibcount` with a string, and then using it as an integer. Does Kip Irvine have a `ReadInt` or so?

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: It's unlikely that the addition of that instruction would create an infinite loop. Don't you have a debugger you can use to single-step through your code as it's executing?

Comment: figured it out.  When I did the readint, I didn't assign it to fibCount.  Fixed it.